# Find duplicates in Mongo DB array across multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to use the mongodb aggregation framework to find duplicates in document arrays?

Here is a simplified version of the **box** collection:

```
{_id : 1, name : 'Box 1', products : [
 {pId : 123, name : 'sneaker'},
 {pId : 456, name : 'pants'},
 {pId : 789, name : 'shirt'}
]},
{_id : 2, name : 'Box 2', products : [
 {pId : 123, name : 'sneaker'},
 {pId : 456, name : 'pants'},
 {pId : 111, name : 'socks'}
]},
{_id : 3, name : 'Box 3', products : [
 {pId : 123, name : 'sneaker'},
 {pId : 222, name : 'belt'},
 {pId : 333, name : 'shorts'}
]}
```

Lets say I want to check if the box 1 products are part of any other boxes.
Can I use the aggregation framework like this:

```
box.aggregate([
 {$match: {'products.pId' : {$in :  [123, 456, 789]}},
 //  ??   //
 ]);
```

Ideally I am hoping for an output like this:

```
[{_id : 123, count : 3,
 {_id : 456, count : 2,
 {_id : 789, count : 1}]
```

I know this can be achieved by returning all docs and them looping over each products array but wanted to see if mongodb can export this directly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way using aggregation:

- First `$unwind` to get every element in product array separated to can group them
- Second `$group` by `products.pId` and create a new field called `count` with the `$sum` for every one that exists.
- And the last step is `$match` the values you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$products.pId",
      "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {"_id": {$in: [123,456,789]}}
  },
  
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0RJuxf-vdZe)

Answer (score 0):

```
 mongos> db.box.aggregate([ {$match:{"products.pId":{$in:[123,456,789]}}} ,{ $unwind:"$products"}   ,{ $group:{_id:"$products.pId" , count:{$sum:1} , containedIn:{$addToSet:"$name"}    }}    ,{$match:{count:{$gt:1}}}  ])
 { "_id" : 123, "count" : 3, "containedIn" : [ "Box 3", "Box 1", "Box 2" ] }
 { "_id" : 456, "count" : 2, "containedIn" : [ "Box 1", "Box 2" ] }
 mongos>
```

explanation:

1. Match the pId that you need
2. Group to find how many there is per pId and in which Box there is duplicates
3. Match count>1 to show only the duplicates

Comment: Thank you R2D2! I like JFs answer because I can search the whole collection without knowing the number of boxes.

Comment: For bigger collection mine will be faster ;)